# Numpy multiply NxD by NxK to KxNxD

Tags: numpy, matrix

So I have a A=NxD matrix that I'm trying to multiply each vector of length D by the B=NxK matrix to make a KxNxD matrix. As in all N vectors should be multiplied by K different perspective Ns in B.

I tried

```
A[:,None] * B
A[:,None,:] * B[None,:,:]
A * B[None, :]
```

They all kind of give the same thing, which is an NxNxK or NxNxD

So for example

```
A = [[1,0], [1,1]]
B = [[1, 1, 1], [2,2,2]]
```

Should give C which will be

```
C[0] = [[1,1,1], [2,2,2]]
```

Because a[0,:] = [[1],[1]] times B and

```
C[1] = [[0, 0, 0], [2,2,2]]
```

Comment: Please add a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can help you more

Comment: `A[:,:,None]*B[:,None,:]` should create a (N,D,K).